# LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished not called if activity is not active

Tags: android, android-activity, android-cursorloader, observers

I have two activities who read the same database table. In activity `A` I have an `AsyncTaskLoader` and `LoaderCallbacks` objects with the following `onLoadFinished` code (in Scala):

```
def onLoadFinished(loader: CursorLoader, cursor: Cursor) = {

  android.util.Log.d(TAG, "got results")
  cursor.setNotificationUri(ct.getContentResolver, observePath)

  cursor registerContentObserver new ContentObserver(new Handler) {
    override def onChange(selfChange: Boolean) = {
      android.util.Log.d(TAG, "change registered")
      if (null != loader) loader.onContentChanged
    }
    override def deliverSelfNotifications = true
  }
}
```

Now, if I go to activity `B`, update database there and call this:

```
getContentResolver.notifyChange(observePath, null)
```

then `onLoadFinished` in activity A is never called although I do get `"change registered"` output in console.
But if I set a few seconds delay so that I have time to return to activity `A` before the code above is executed, then `onLoadFinished` is called normally.

It seems `LoaderCallbacks` methods are somehow dependent on the host activity being active but I don't want that, I want `onLoadFinished` to be called even if activity A is in background. How can I achieve that?

Comment: LoaderCallbacks are tied to the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, this is by design. The loaders will still run to completion, but you will not get the callback until you return to the activity (and call initLoader() again to reconnect the callbacks).