# onLoadFinished() not getting called when activity is in onstop state

Tags: android, loader

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

These sources say : You typically initialize a `Loader` within the activity's `onCreate()` method.

But I receive data from bluetooth by connecting to a device and gives me some parameters that are required to make the web call.

Now in between here if the user clicks home button, then activity goes in `onstop` state.

Now in between on receiving those parameters from bluetooth, I get a call back to `isCompleteParametersRetrieved()` method ,where i call `initloader()` to start my loader.

I found another question of same kind [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609166/loadercallbacks-onloadfinished-not-called-if-activity-is-not-active)
But there is no solution as to what can be done ..

I am attaching logs here :

```
onStart of Activity Home
onResume of Activity Home 
onPause of Activity Home 
onStop of Activity Home 
isCompleteParametersRetrieved()
initLoader of Activity Home called 
onCreateLoader of Activity Home called
```

Now after `onCreateLoader()` gets called in Activity Home's `onStop` state but `onLoadfinished` never gets called ..

Comment: Its my activity

Comment: what is your code actually?